# Update the values ​of a json file in wordpress

Tags: json

Should I change the data a json file through wordpress.
Maybe create custom post type from json file.
Do you have any advice or another solution?
The file is hosted on the same server where there is wordpress

This is the structure of my json file

```
var DATA = {
  "points": [
    {
      "id": "point-1",
      "name": "point-name-1",

      "Parameters": {
        "par1": 001,
        "par2": 003,
        "par3": 004
      },
      "pointdetails": [
        {
          "text": 'lorm',
          "url": 'myurl',
        },  
        {
          "text2": 'lorm',
          "url2": 'myurl',
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": "point-2",
      "name": "point-name-2",

      "Parameters": {
        "par1": 001,
        "par2": 003,
        "par3": 004
      },
      "pointdetails": [
        {
          "text": 'lorm',
          "url": 'myurl',
        },
        {
          "text2": 'lorm',
          "url2": 'myurl',
        }
      ]
    }   
  ]
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your post, but would you please edit your question and provide some more details? For example: Where did this file come from originally? What data does it contain? Is it generated and managed via another source?

Comment: Sorry...I edited the question.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to _edit JSON from within WordPress_ ?